# Making columns wider in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart graph that combined a quarterly dataseries with a daily series. The daily series is shown as a column and the daily is shown as a line. Each quarter is mapped to a day in the last month of the quarter. My problem is when I have a years worth or more of data shown each quarter-column becomes very thin. This is because it is mapped to a single day and there only occupy the width of a single day. What I need help figuring out is how to make the columns appear wider so it looks like they're not only showing data for a single day.

I've tried setting a higher borderWidth to columns, and while that did help, it wasn't really a good enough solution.

Here's a fiddle to show my problem and the series I wish to make wider:

http://jsfiddle.net/h3Gt9/2/

```
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Line 2',
            color: '#000000',
            data: [{x: Date.UTC(2012, 3, 01), y: 1.707},
                   {x: Date.UTC(2012, 6, 01), y: 0.71}, 
                   {x: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 01), y: 0.106}, 
                   {x: Date.UTC(2012, 12, 01), y: 0.129}, 
                   {x: Date.UTC(2013, 3, 01), y: 0.144}, 
                   {x: Date.UTC(2013, 6, 01), y: 0.176},
                   {x: Date.UTC(2013, 9, 01), y: 0.135}]
```

And a fiddle with what I've tried with borders: http://jsfiddle.net/h3Gt9/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/h3Gt9/3/)

Use the pointWidth option like so:

```
{
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Line 2',
  color: '#000000',
  pointWidth: 80
  // ...
}
```

EDIT: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth

Comment: This solved the case for me, but I'll also take a look into Sebastians advice

Answer (score 4):

Point width is resposible for it but I advice to familair with other parameters like:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.groupPadding
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPadding

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it. pointWidth did solve this particular case for me, but I'm sure I can make a even better solution by looking into your tips

Comment: yeah this turns out to be a better and more responsive answer.